# JPA releations between OneToMany And ManyToOne

Tags: java, jpa, entity-relationship

I'm new to JPA and trying to do relations between two tables like this:

This is the main class object `XParserLinks`:

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "link_id")
    private Integer linkId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "xParserLink", targetEntity = XLinksMedia.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<XLinksMedia> fotos;
    ...
```

This is the object class `XLinksMedia`

```
public class XLinksMedia implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected XLinksMediaPK xLinksMediaPK;
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "link_id")
    private XParserLinks xParserLink;
```

and `XLinksMediaPK`

```
@Embeddable
public class XLinksMediaPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "link_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int linkId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;
```

Are these relations correct? Because when I want to add new `XLinksMedia` objects in `fotos` list, I get `LinkId = 0`, but I know that `LinkId` is not `0`, I know that `LinkId` variable have a value.

Here's how I try to set `fotos` variable in `XParseLinks` class (`preke`: is `XParseLinks` object witch have his primary key `LinkId`):

```
XLinksMedia foto = new XLinksMedia();
foto.setXLinksMediaPK(new XLinksMediaPK());

foto.setxParserLink(preke);
foto.getXLinksMediaPK().setImage(e.attr("src"));

preke.getFotos().add(foto);
```

Comment: You need a MapsId annotation on the ManyToOne. But really do yourself a favor, and add an auto-generated, single-colum ID to the XLinksMedia entity: everything will be much easier, and also more efficient.

Comment: We cannot get what is your expectation? did you get any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I don't know what is your expectation, When I test your coding, it is OK. I just put some of the `OverLoad Constructor` for easy data initialization in your classes. But, you use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, that's why I set auto increate column for `link_id` of `XParserLinks`. The main of the following coding is same as yours.

Your point `Here's how I try to set fotos variable in XParseLinks class (preke: is XParseLinks object witch have his primary key LinkId):`. Check `Test.java`

XParserLinks.java

```
@Entity
public class XParserLinks implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "link_id")
    private Integer linkId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "xParserLink", targetEntity = XLinksMedia.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<XLinksMedia> fotos;

    private String something;

    public XParserLinks() {
        fotos = new ArrayList<XLinksMedia>();
    }

    public XParserLinks(String something) {
        this.something = something;
        fotos = new ArrayList<XLinksMedia>();
    }
    //getter and setter
}
```

XLinksMediaPK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class XLinksMediaPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "link_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int linkId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;

    public XLinksMediaPK(){
    }

    public XLinksMediaPK(int linkId, String image) {
        this.linkId = linkId;
        this.image = image;
    }
    //getter and setter
}
```

XParserLinks.java

```
@Entity
public class XParserLinks implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "link_id")
    private Integer linkId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "xParserLink", targetEntity = XLinksMedia.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<XLinksMedia> fotos;

    private String something;

    public XParserLinks() {
        fotos = new ArrayList<XLinksMedia>();
    }

    public XParserLinks(String something) {
        this.something = something;
        fotos = new ArrayList<XLinksMedia>();
    }
    //getter and setter

    public void add(XLinksMedia media) {
        fotos.add(media);
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        XParserLinks xParserLink = new XParserLinks("something");

        XLinksMediaPK pk1 = new XLinksMediaPK(0, "image_1");
        XLinksMediaPK pk2 = new XLinksMediaPK(0, "image_2");
        XLinksMediaPK pk3 = new XLinksMediaPK(0, "image_3");

        xParserLink.add(new XLinksMedia(pk1, xParserLink));
        xParserLink.add(new XLinksMedia(pk2, xParserLink));
        xParserLink.add(new XLinksMedia(pk3, xParserLink));

        em.persist(xParserLink);

        System.out.println("Success...");

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
}
```